# status 403 forbidden Postman- Spring Security Basic

Tags: spring, mongodb, model-view-controller, postman, basic-authentication

hello, I'm trying to make a post request where I create the user indicating username password and Email; the post gives me the error 403 forbidden, this is strange because the getUser returns correctly the user body; I write the code using SpringBoot and MongoDBcompass;

postman request:

```
{
    "username":"UserProva",
    "email":"emailprova@gmail.com",
    "password":"provaPass"
}
```

This is my configuration for spring authentication:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    //configuro le api da autenticare e quelle permesse da tutti
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz
                .anyRequest().authenticated());
        http.formLogin(withDefaults());
        http.httpBasic(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

this is my UserController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserController implements UserAPI {

    @Autowired
    private final UserService userService;
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(String id_user) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(userService.getUser(id_user), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<String> createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        userService.createUser(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I have tried many ways to change the configuration but I can't access the postman's post